Missing icons in material icons extended package
I'm trying to use the cellphone material icon in Compose Multi-Platform.
I've added the following line in root/composeApp/build.gradle.kts:
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended) // this one
        }
    }
}

But when referencing Icons.Default.CellPhone or Cellphone, it appears to not exist.
Do I need to change the imported version of the package? (If so how?)
Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

I had the same problem. In my case, I needed to delete the .gradle and .idea directory and restart Android Studio. Once I did that it worked.

I simply use the icons that comes with Android Studio. Serves me most times
